# Binding different Models to different PivotItems

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm

Is it possible to bind different models to different PivotItems in a Pivot-Control?

My PivotItems are

- Page 1
- Page 2

And on both pages I Need different data to Show with different DataTemplates.
If yes, can someone show a simple sample?

Comment: By Model do you mean DataContext?

Comment: Yes. Can u help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your PivotItems to be managed from the different ViewModels, all you have to do is assign each PivotItem with dedicated ViewModel, e.g.:

```
<Pivot x:Name="PivotContro>
  <PivotItem x:Name="Page1" DataContext="{Binding FirstViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelProvider}}" />
  <PivotItem x:Name="Page2" DataContext="{Binding SecondViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelProvider}}" />
</Pivot>
```

Comment: Cool. Looks easy and I´ll try this. Can I add there my DesignData too?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'm not 100% sure about DesignData, but you can definitely can use d:DataContext feature, which in many basic uses boils down to the same thing.